# winrt IBuffer in Python

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, windows-runtime

I am using winrt in python to read sensor data over Bluetooth. This returns a `_winrt_Windows_Storage_Streams.IBuffer` object. Does anyone know how to turn this into a nice python object?

Comment: The interface has a `data()` method that returns a byte pointer to the buffer.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.ibuffer .

Comment: How does this work in python? I can't seem to figure it out. Which object/class should have the data method? It doesn't look like IBuffers directly have a data method as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1):

[Bleak](https://github.com/hbldh/bleak) is a cross-platform Bluetooth Low Energy client Python library that may be a better solution than using the Windows runtime APIs directly. It has a simplified API and already handles the conversion of `IBuffer` to `bytearray`.

Under the hood, Bleak uses [bleak-winrt](https://github.com/dlech/bleak-winrt) to provide Python bindings to the Windows SDK. These bindings are automatically generated using [PyWinRT](https://github.com/pywinrt/pywinrt).
These projects are based on the same code but have many improvements over the seemingly unmaintained [winrt](https://pypi.org/project/winrt/) package from the [xlang](https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang) project.

The `bleak-winrt` bindings implement the [Python buffer protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/buffer.html) for the `IBuffer` interface. So you can pass the `IBuffer` object directly to any Python API that uses the Python buffer protocol. For example, if the data is structured (as opposed to a stream), then `struct.unpack()` is probably quite useful in this case.